# Sencha Touch - getting value from number field

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, dom, sencha-touch

I've just gotten started using the Sencha Touch 2 framework, and am having some difficulty in replicating form behaviour across devices. I have a simple search bar, where a user enters a value (all numbers), and chooses what it represents (an account, order, or phone number). When a user clicks/taps on the search button, it grabs the value of the input field and the currently pressed data-type button and makes an AJAX query to a PHP script. On a PC, it works without issue. On an iPad (6.1.3), the GET request doesn't hit the server, and the getValue function reports a NULL, even when the field is filled. What am I missing here?

```
Ext.define('bazooka.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
requires: ['Ext.form.Panel', 'Ext.form.FieldSet', 'Ext.field.Text', 'Ext.field.Email', 'Ext.field.TextArea', 'Ext.field.Number', 'Ext.SegmentedButton'],

config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    tabBar: {
        ui: Ext.filterPlatform('blackberry') || Ext.filterPlatform('ie10') ? 'dark' : 'light',
        layout: {
            pack : 'center',
            align: 'center'
        },
        docked: 'bottom'
    },
    items: [
        {
            title: 'Home',
            iconCls: 'home',
            html: 'This will have news and updates for the department of the currently authenticated user.'
        },
        {
            title: 'Lookup',
            iconCls: 'search',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    ui: Ext.filterPlatform('blackberry') || Ext.filterPlatform('ie10') ? 'dark' : 'light',
                    docked: 'top',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'numberfield',
                            id: 'viki_searchbox',
                            autoComplete: false,
                            autoCorrect: false,
                            docked: 'left',
                            maxWidth: '40%'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'segmentedbutton',
                            id: 'viki_seg_btn',
                            allowDepress: true,
                            items: [
                                {
                                    id: 'account',
                                    iconCls: 'user'
                                },
                                {
                                    id: 'workorder',
                                    iconCls: 'time'
                                },
                                {
                                    id: 'telephone',
                                    iconCls: 'more'
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            id: 'viki_searchbutton',
                            docked: 'right',
                            iconCls: 'search',
                            handler: function() {
                                var searchtype = Ext.getCmp('viki_seg_btn').getPressedButtons()[0]["id"];
                                var searchvalue = Ext.getCmp('viki_searchbox').getValue();
                                Ext.Viewport.setMasked({
                                    xtype: 'loadmask',
                                    message: 'Searching...'
                                });
                                Ext.Ajax.request({
                                    url: 'viki.php',
                                    method: 'GET',
                                    headers: {
                                        "Content-Type": "application/xml"
                                    },
                                    disableCaching: false,
                                    params: {
                                        type: searchtype,
                                        sv: searchvalue
                                    },
                                    timeout: 3000,
                                    failure: function(response) {
                                        console.log("oops");
                                    }
                                });
                                Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use handler often, I prefer Tap Events.

The problem might be that choice.

Plus, if I were you I would be using ItemId and not Id and getComponent() and not getCmp().

Since your search button is in the same view form it you would be able to retrieve values

```
searchbutton.getParent().getComponent('itemId').value;
```

I make these recommandations, has I experienced lots of strange behavior in sencha when using global object (like id or getCmp).  it would be safer with itemId and getComponent().

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're view is a numberfield.
Number field will return null if there's user input that has non-numeric characters.